# Time Derivative defined by Fermi transport in Kerr Space-Time

Tags: general-relativity, kerr-metric

I have been studying 3+1 GR the last weeks. I have tried to comprehend

> Electrodynamics in curved space-time: 3+1 formulation (1982) Thorne McDonald

I have studied another 3+1 GR book but it didn't contain "Fermi Transport" and generally, I'm not that experienced with GR. (Just started  these past 2 months)

$$\begin{align}
D_\tau M^\beta &= \gamma ^{\beta \mu} M_{\mu ; \nu} U^\nu \\
&= M^{\beta}_{;\mu} U^{\mu} - U^\beta U_{\mu; \sigma}U^{\sigma}M^{\mu}\\
\end{align}
$$

If I apply the Einstein notion, I get only the 1st term. How does the second one come up?

$M$ is a vector with space-time components but only spatial are non-zero.
$\gamma $ is the metric of 3-space and $U$ is the ZAMO's 4-vel in a Kerr Metric.